# Output between two dates mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need the out in MYSQL like this.

Records :

```
start_date |  to_date
2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31
2013-02-01 | 2013-05-04
2013-01-30 | 2013-04-02
2013-04-30 | 2013-07-06
2013-06-30 | 2013-06-09
2013-08-30 | 2013-10-03
```

my input is from_date 2013-04-01 and to_date 2013-06-10

my out put shuld be like this :

```
start_date | to_date
2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31
2013-02-01 | 2013-05-04
2013-01-30 | 2013-04-02
2013-04-30 | 2013-07-06
2013-06-30 | 2013-06-09
```

can any one help on this.

Comment: am I to stupid to see the idea behind "should be like this"? what are you grouping/filtering by?

Comment: My guess: user inputs a date range (from_date to to_date). Whenever this date range overlaps with one of the ranges in the db, it should output the range from the db. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to find ranges overlapping your given range;

```
SELECT * FROM date_table 
WHERE start_date < '2013-06-10'
  AND to_date   > '2013-04-01'
```

That is, you compare your from_date with the column `to_date` and your to_date with the column `start_date`.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeb58/2).

Comment: lsaksson but i m not getting any out for this query SELECT * FROM date_table 
WHERE start_date < '2013-01-01'
  AND to_date   > '2013-04-01'

Comment: @BashaGhouse See the order of the dates in my query, the later date comes in the first condition.